# Save a material in a slot to a new material library

Tags: maxscript

Using maxscript I want to know how to save a material in a slot to a material library.

I already know that I can get a slot material by:

```
myMaterial = meditMaterials[i]
```

Where i is the slot number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use append to add a material or a texture to a material library, e.g.:

```
append currentMaterialLibrary meditMaterials[activeMeditSlot]
```